# Google search input text box can be found using name but not id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to go to the url "https://www.google.co.in" enter the word "Googling" in the input text box and then click on the search button.

The input text box has id "gs_htif0".

So the statement

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Googling");
```

should work. But it's not. The statement

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKey("Googling");
```

is working fine. It fills the search box with the word "Googling".

Comment: What's the question? You show code that "doesn't work" (and don't specify what's wrong), and then show code that works.

Comment: Hi bro, an argument is making a difference here. I got the logic right but the chosen the wrong argument.  I want clarification on that. So I hoped someone here might help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tried incorrect id. Please check with :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Googling");
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. What I did earlier is I inspected the search input box with firebug and the input tag with the id "gs_htif0" is highlighted in the source code. So I used it but in vain. I can see that you've used the id of the input tag which is above the input the tag I referred. Why?

Comment: Because your `input` is hidden.

Comment: You did right but found wrong element. Always make sure that element should no be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes in identifying the correct one in locating an element. How can I distinguish between hidden and non-hidden?

Comment: You should see some css property like visibility:hidden with input element. That means it is hidden.